# Angular Router issue - links are not clickable

Tags: angular2-routing

I have a simple routing module, and then a template where I have links. 
- The first  link doesn't display as a clickable link, it shows as static text.

- The second  shows as link, only because of the href. Is this required?

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ListComponent} from "./list/list.component"

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'List', component: ListComponent},
    {path: 'Home', component: AppComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <a routerLink="/List" routerLinkActive="active">List</a> |
    <a href="./list/list.component.html" routerlink="/List" routerLinkActive="active">List</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `href` is not required and the second one it should be `routerLink` not `routerlink`.

Try using lower caps in your links

Why would you need both links to point to the same thing

Comment: I added the line with the href just for testing purposes, to show that href makes the link clickable. Using routerLink and lower caps links didn't work. 

It looks like the component is not reading the router module, or some dependent aspect is not being loaded, which is preventing the <a routerLink...> as being rendered as a clickable link.